# Как отловить редирект и перейти по нему в браузере?

Tags: javascript

Суть в том что когда гость заходит по урлу /cabinet/history у нас выполняется ajax-запрос на сервер чтобы получить историю заказов отдельным куском html. Это позволяет отобразить страницу еще до того как история будет готова. И вместо истории заказов мы показываем лоадер. Но есть проблема. Если гость не авторизован, то ему возвращается редирект при этом ajax-запросе. Нужно обнаружить эту ситуацию и перейти по редиректу. Сейчас вместо этого кусок, который должен отображать историю показывает результат редиректа (редирект идет на логина и получается, что сайт как бы дублируется). Форматом ответа может быть только html в данном случае. Как отловить редирект и перейти по нему в браузере, а не только этим куском html?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так в ответе от сервера что? 30x редирект или 200 и контент?

Comment: @aepot в качестве ответа от сервера приходит html который содержит страницу с login

Comment: Статус ответа какой, что promise содержит? Вы знаете, что такое AJAX запрос? В курсе что такое HTTP статус код в ответе от сервера?

Comment: Вот что пришло в ответе data: html document, textSatus: success, jqXHR.status: 200

Comment: Ну тогда вопросы к серверу, почему он отдает целую страницу, а не фрагмент.

Answer (score 1):

> то ему возвращается редирект при этом ajax-запросе

Это неправильная логика работы в принципе. Почему при запросе истории у вас возвращается редирект на логин?

Правильно будет при загрузке любой страницы **вначале проверить юзера** и его права, роли и доступ (обычно у всех сайтов есть единая точка доступа и там работает обработчик запросов и можно при init'e приложения это проверить). Если он гость - кинуть на страницу логина. Если не гость - то только тогда уже загружать страницу `/cabinet/history`.

Comment: В нашей системе страницы и блоки могут настраиваться и были созданы для менеджеров - технически не подготовленных сотрудников.
Логика настройки состоит в том, что страница только отображает выбранный блок и не имеет информации о том какие блоки и каких настроек могут требовать, потому проверки должны быть зашиты в сами блоки.
Про страницы и блоки: https://docs.arora.pro/arora/satellite/satellite-common.html
Проблема эта возникла потому что единственный блок, который требует авторизации (блок истории) отображается на странице с помощью JS, который запрашивает его уже после загрузки страницы.